# SQL SERVER : populating a column based on other other columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a tableA: (ID int, matchPID char,PID char, set int, num char, QID char, QStatus char)

```
ID matchPID   PID    set  num   QID  QStatus 
1  00001230   xx123   1   234  
2  00001229   xx234   1   214
3  00000054   xx654   1   NULL
4  00012000   xx125   2   
5  00A53214   xx321   2   
6  00000100   xx213   2
```

matchPID is always (00-xxxxxx) x can be char or int.

now I have to populate OID just one value for each set according to [num].

1. If for any set, there exists any value in [num], then populate OID with PID where exists [num] for same set and populate Qstatus = 'fail' in rest.

so OID can be populated in id 1 or 2. (any1), then check lowest matchPID and populate here. so in this case (set1) expected result is :

```
ID matchPID   PID    set  num   QID       QStatus 

1  00001230   xx123   1   234   NULL       FAIL
2  00001229   xx234   1   214   xx234      NULL
3  00000054   xx654   1   NULL  NULL       FAIL
```

1. if for any set there isnt any [num] found, then pick lowest matchPID and populate QID with PID and fail the rest.

notice that matchPID starts with 00 and then it can be 0>1>2>..>A>B>C>....
so expected result for set2 is :

```
ID matchPID   PID    set  num   QID       QStatus

4  00012000   xx125   2   NULL  NULL      FAIL
5  00A53214   xx321   2   NULL  NULL      FAIL
6  00000100   xx213   2   NULL  xx213     NULL
```

Thanks

Comment: Nice problem. What have you tried so far?

Comment: uushh. I am trying simple update command with case for where exists but it is getting creepy and complicated. I need clean update statement. Thanks :)

Comment: What Adrian was getting at is, please show us the query you've attempted, and we can try to correct / improve it.

Comment: Try updating the question, posting what you have tried so far. You'll see the folks around here like to see that you put some effort into it.

Comment: sorry guys I accidently deleted that query. I was trying it for 30 minutes but not getting any closer results. Frustration and lazyness leads me here. Let me see if I hve back up but no promises.

Comment: I liked the "no promises" part. It's bi-directional

Comment: 26 views and zero Answer. LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want something like this?:

```
;WITH setInfo AS (
SELECT [SET], 
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableA b 
                                WHERE b.[set]=a.[set] AND num IS NOT NULL) 
                                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasNum,
    MIN(matchPID) AS MinMatchPID
FROM tableA a
GROUP BY [SET]
)
UPDATE a SET
QID = CASE WHEN s.HasNum = 0 AND a.matchPID = s.MinMatchPID THEN a.PID
           WHEN s.HasNum = 0 AND a.matchPID != s.MinMatchPID THEN NULL
           WHEN s.HasNum = 1 AND a.matchPID = (SELECT min(matchpid) FROM tableA b
                                     WHERE b.[set] = a.[set]
                                     AND b.num is not null
                                      ) 
                                     THEN a.PID
           ELSE NULL
           END,
QStatus = CASE WHEN s.HasNum = 0 AND a.matchPID = s.MinMatchPID THEN NULL
           WHEN s.HasNum = 0 AND a.matchPID != s.MinMatchPID THEN 'FAIL'
           WHEN s.HasNum = 1 AND a.matchPID = (SELECT min(matchpid) FROM tableA b
                                     WHERE b.[set] = a.[set]
                                     AND b.num is not null
                                      ) 
                                     THEN a.PID
           ELSE 'FAIL'
           END
FROM tableA a
JOIN setInfo s ON s.[set] = a.[set]
```

Comment: No, I actually did it in two update statements , first is taking care of set1 in example and second is taking care of set2 in example. then update Qstatus where QID is NULL.

Comment: BTW, where is "SetInfo" coming from ? Its just one table TableA. Thanks

Comment: setInfo was a common-table-expression that I created to group by set and use in the single update logic.  It's not another table.  It's like a temporary table that only lives for the duration of the query.  I like them better than derived tables, because they are defined above the main query and keep it cleaner.  There are other potential advantages like recursion, joining multiple times to one definition, having multiple CTEs where later ones can reference earlier ones...

Comment: GREAT !   But it works for set#2 whereas it is failing all values of set1. P.S. only one value of each set MUST be populated in QID.

Comment: I'm not sure what's failing.  It seems to work with my test, using your data.  I was guessing that what you meant by "where exists [num] for same set" was that the right 3 characters of Pid matched a Num value in that set.  I'm not sure which row you'd update if none of the num values matched.  If you add more detail, perhaps I can change the query to accommodate it for you.

Comment: WHEN s.HasNum = 1 AND a.matchPID = (SELECT min(matchpid) FROM tableA b
                                     WHERE b.[set] = a.[set]
                                     AND b.num is not null
                                      ) 
                                     THEN a.PID